# if block not working as expected in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Following jQuery function is being called from a View in an ASP.Net MVC3 project:

```
function ValidateRequestor() {
    var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

    var frstNameval = $('[id*=FirstName]').val();
    if (!(/[a-z]/i.test(frstNameval))) {
        $('[id*=FirstName]').val("");
        $('[id*=FirstName]').focus();
        alert("Please specify a proper first name.");
        return false;
    }
    if (frstNameval == '') {
        alert("Please specify a first name.");
        return false;
    }
    var lstNameval = $('[id*=LastName]').val();
    if (!(/[a-z]/i.test(lstNameval))) {
        $('[id*=LastName]').val("");
        $('[id*=LastName]').focus();
        alert("Please specify a proper last name.");
        return false;
    }
    if (lstNameval == '') {
        alert("Please specify a last name.");
        return false;
    }

//    var Approvedval = $('#_SelectedGeography').val();
//    //debugger;
    if ($('#_SelectedGeography').val() == '') {
        alert("Please specify Approval Group.");
        return false;
    }
    debugger;
    if ($('#TextFAFM').length > 0) {
        if ($('#TextFAFM').val().length>0) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ($('#TextFAFM').val() == '') {
            alert("Please specify Financial Analyst.");
            return false;
        }        
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

However the below block of code is not working as expected:

```
if ($('#TextFAFM').length > 0) {
            if ($('#TextFAFM').val().length>0) {
                return true;
            }
            else if ($('#TextFAFM').val() == '') {
                alert("Please specify Financial Analyst.");
                return false;
            }        
        }
```

The block which returns True is not getting executed. Please help.

Comment: does TextFAFM element has any values?

Comment: `$('#TextFAFM')` Does this element exists?

Comment: Why on earth are you not using jquery unobtrusive validation?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i guess just a matter of avoiding usage of other lib.

Comment: yes $('#TextFAFM') exists and it has value, still the true block is not getting executed.

Comment: `$('#TextFAFM')` might be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it this way?

```
if ($('#TextFAFM').length > 0) {
            if ($('#TextFAFM').val() == '') 
            {
                alert("Please specify Financial Analyst.");
                return false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Or, better use like this:

```
if ($('#TextFAFM').length > 0) {
var txtVal = $('#TextFAFM').val();
            if (txtVal.length>0) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (txtVal == '') {
                alert("Please specify Financial Analyst.");
                return false;
            }        
        }
```